# Facebook and Gmail stop working after 10 minutes

Tags: 10.10, networking, firefox, 64-bit, google-chrome

I have problems with facebook and gmail only: It works fine and lets me log in, view the content, read new messages, etc. But after 5-10 minutes it doesn't load at all:

> This webpage is not available.
>
> The webpage at
>   http://www.facebook.com/ might be
>   temporarily down or it may have moved
>   permanently to a new web address.
>
> More information on this error Below
>   is the original error message
>
> ```
> Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET):
> Unknown error
> ```

After deleting cookies this problem disappears for 5-10 minutes, then I get the same error. It happens with Google Chrome and Firefox. Ping works fine.

I have checked *System → Preferences → Network Proxy*, it's set to the default: "Direct Internet Connection". Then I ran the test  at `chrome://net-internals/#tests` and got some "FAIL" results

> - Use system proxy settings
> - Disable IPv6 host resolving
> - Probe for IPv6 host resolving

IPv6 is disabled.

Comment: @Julia, how do you connect to the internet? Is there a proxy server involved, or some kind of content-filtering or session-aware firewall?

Comment: Also, a Google employee (in a thread at http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=261ff247ac4dd565&hl=en) recommends that you navigate to “chrome://net-internals/#tests”, and enter the address you're having trouble with to get some diagnostics. (Wait until you are having the problem to run the tests.) Please edit your question to include this information, and hopefully someone will be able to help you.

Comment: @Julia, by chance do you have both a wired and wireless connection enabled? If so, maybe try turning off the one you're not using. Looks like there is a bug when switching networks: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=19472

Comment: There is no wireless connections only wired standard Auto eth0

Comment: The tests' results look normal to me.

Comment: Do other sites work when you cant access FB or Gmail? Where is this error message shown? FF usually shows "Server server.tld is responding too slowly",etc Are you using an proxy?

Comment: Can you copy'n'paste output of ifconfig?

Comment: papukaija, other sites works normal, without any problems or disfuntions. I've turned off all proxies.

Comment: 1. Can you try it with flash disabled?
2. Have you disabled all extensions and plugins and tried it yet? (What other extensions do you have installed?)
3. Are you wired directly into a modem, or do you go through a router?

    * If through a router, what model? Any custom firmware?

Comment: Since you mention that the situation changes when you delete cookies: maybe you can test the effect of blocking cookies (http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Blocking%20cookies ) This may tell us whether the problem is caused by too many or too few cookies.

Comment: What kind of DNS servers do you use? I had similar issue with unbound running on localhost and using that as nameserver (nameserver 127.0.0.1 in /etc/resolv.conf). Problem was resolved when I removed that line from /etc/resolv.conf No idea why we use unbound on ISP level too, and there is no such a problem there!!

Comment: Scaine, I did it already. I've changed the DNS entries to Google's entries, but it didn't solve the problem. Empathy and Skype also doesn't work. Gmail throw me out after log in, I can't edit my account settings. I'm running between Win and Ubuntu at the same macshine


Jim, it was "true", I did it... I think I've tried everything.

Comment: Is the same for all users?..

Answer (score 3):

Some troubleshooting ideas :

Start a terminal and run `watch -d -n 20 dig www.facebook.com`.  Then, the moment that gmail or facebook shows the error, ALT-TAB to your terminal window and watch the next update for any changes.  I'm guessing that these sites have load balancers in place that are changing the IP addresses behind the scenes.  It's possible that your ISP is caching the content without your knowledge and your cookie is becoming invalid because the content being provided by your ISP is no longer a match for the connection being made by your browser.

[image: watch -d -n 20 dig www.facebook.com]

You *might* be able to circumvent this by changing your DNS servers.  Try right clicking on nm-applet, then choose "Edit Connections".  Choose your ethernet connection (probably "auto eth0"), then "Edit".  Go to the IPv4 settings and change "Automatic DHCP" to "Automatic DHCP (addresses only)".

[image: Editing auto eth0]

All your going to change is the DNS entries - either use Google's entries (enter `8.8.8.8, 4.4.4.4`), or OpenDNS (enter `208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220`)

I suppose the other option for possibly circumventing such a time-out is to run Gmail over https.  Not sure if Facebook supports fully encrypted sessions.  To set Gmail to use https, go to your account settings at the top-right of the page, then in the General tab, find the "Use HTTPS" option and select it.

[image: Gmail Settings]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Firefox.  Even though I had IPV6 disabled on the system, I still had to disable it within Firefox.

I went to `About:Config`
Entered `IPV6` as the search term.
Changed value for `network.dns.disableIPv6` from false to `true`

I don't know if it will help you, but that worked for me.

Comment: That's not future-proof though, the way IPv4 is heading...